# Highcharts : Group the series in a column chart having multiple series and show space between the groups

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, data-visualization

Highcharts demos have an example of Stacked and Grouped column chart.Refer following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/aqpp99uq/

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
}
```

I would like to group the series in a column chart having multiple series and show space between the groups. In reference to above example, John & Joe series should be grouped together and Jane & Janet should be grouped together, with spacing between the 2 groups for distinction of the groups.
I have tried one solution by adding dummy series with empty data between the series to be grouped and not showing it in legend. Refer following JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/amrutaJgtp/aqpp99uq/2/

```
{
    //Dummy series with empty data defined to show the gap between 2 groups
    name: 'Temp',
    data: [],
    stack: 'male',
    showInLegend: false
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this result of grouping series in column chart and add space between the groups, without creating the dummy series with empty data?
Or can highcharts provide any attribute to achieve the same?

Comment: I think that you should be able to use pointPlacement parameter for positioning your columns: https://jsfiddle.net/aqpp99uq/3/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Yes, setting the pointPlacement is one way. But i dont want to hardcode the value of pointPlacement, since the number of groups may vary. Hence maybe the values of pointPlacement should be calculated at run time and set or need some other solution.

Comment: I think that the easier idea how to create your chart is to add series just like you shown in your question

Comment: @Ams I think this might help you